Is there any different pattern to built a 3x3 magic square?
After reading and verifying everything stated here about 3x3 magic squares, I conclude that, in summary, this is the basic concept of their structure and that there cannot exist another one that deviates from the patterns of the Lo Shu:
1 - Due to the nature of the structure of a 3x3 magic square, all possible arrangements are essentially the Lo Shu pattern or one of its variants by rotation or reflection. (INCORRECT);
2 - This structure does not depend specifically on the numbers 1 to 9; it can use any set of nine values as long as the correlation between them is proportional. (CORRECT);
3 - However, the relative position of the numbers—especially those corresponding to the intermediate set when ordered—will always follow the same type of symmetry. (INCORRECT);
4 - In the case of the intermediate sequence 4, 5, 6 in the classic square (1 to 9), it has been mathematically demonstrated that, after applying all possible rotations and reflections, this triad (together with the central number) invariably ends up on a diagonal. (CORRECT);
5 - This does not change even when we replace the set 1 to 9 with another set of nine different numbers. As long as you construct a truly magic square (in which rows, columns, and diagonals all add up to the same value), the relative arrangement of the numbers will be equivalent to a transformation of Lo Shu, causing the intermediate set  to also be positioned on a diagonal. It is not possible to place it exclusively in a central horizontal row or a central vertical column without the diagonals also resulting in the same sum, thus maintaining the diagonal alignment of that intermediate set. (INCORRECT);
6 - In short, there is no way to construct an authentic 3x3 magic square in which the intermediate triad (the one that includes the central number and the values immediately "above" and "below" in terms of order) ceases to appear on a diagonal, regardless of the set of nine numbers chosen. (INCORRECT).
In the structure of the 3x3 Lo Shu magic square, all 6 points above must be consistent, and all should be marked as correct.
But they are not.
Points 1, 3, 5, and 6 are incorrect, and I can prove it with several examples.
I would like to know the opinion of those who disagree and those who agree with me.
Thank you for your attention.

Yes, the only way to build a $3\times3$ magic square, up to rotations and reflections, is as you have it. Try to prove it!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988614/ramanujans-method-for-solving-a-magic-square is worth a look.

"I would like to know the opinion of those who disagree and those who agree with me." This is not a matter of opinion, it is a matter of facts. If you can prove it with examples, then do it! But learn how to make it look like $$\matrix{4&11&3\cr5&6&7\cr9&1&8\cr}$$ instead of $4\ 11\ 3\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 9\ 1\ 8$. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023

By the way, if your item 2, "it can use any set of nine values. (CORRECT)" means you think you can arrange any set of nine numbers to make a magic square, that is certainly incorrect. E.g., you can't make a magic square using the nine numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1000$.

@GerryMyerson Here is an example, I have this group of nine numbers to make a 3x3 MSquare:
3, 12, 15 | 21, 24, 27 | 33, 36, 45. Can you make a MSquare with this numbers?

Of course. $$\matrix{33&3&36\cr27&24&21\cr12&45&15\cr}$$  What's your point? Can you make a magic square with the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1000$?

@GerryMyerson "...1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1000?" you know that´s impossible, because doesn't exist an adequate correlation between that numbers to build a 3x3 MSquare.

@GerryMyerson My point it's showing that there is a difference in the way of the numbers flows in their positions from the Lo Shu pattern flowing numbers. In that pattern the intermediate sequence numbers (21, 24, 27) appears always in horizontal central row or in a vertical central column. In Lo Shu pattern the intermediate sequence (like: 4, 5, 6) appears always in a diagonal of the MSquare. That's all. That was my point. That new pattern, you just used, it's only possible because that exists a separation of 3, 6, and 9 between that group of nine numbers. Thank you for your attention.

The difference you are pointing out already appears in the example I posted a few comments up, which I copied from the answer @Oscar posted earlier, so there's nothing new there. Now, what about my attempt to understand what you mean in your item 2, "it can make use of any set of nine values", when as you know only certain very special sets of nine values can be used?

Sorry, @GerryMyerson you are right in your both observations. In point 2. I forgot to add this in the sentence: "(...) as long as the correlation between them is proportional."

I don't know what "as long as the correlation between them is proportional" means. How do you measure a correlation between nine numbers? And to what is that correlation supposed to be proportional?

@GerryMyerson With the space between numbers. The nine numbers I gave you, if you put them in a crescent sequence: 3, 12, 15 | 21, 24, 27 | 33, 36, 45 you will notice they have a 3, 6 and 9 correlation in the difference between them. I called that method I use the 369 flying pattern. English it's not my natural language and It's hard to explain withou any images... I can't go to chat here because I don't have enough points. If you have a private chat I can send you some images. Other thing I use to do it's 3x3 personalized magic squares using birthdates.

You do realize, I hope, that the answer posted by @Chris Lewis gives the complete form for all $3\times3$ magic squares. For example, you can use the numbers $1,5,6,9,10,11,14,15,19$. And in your example, why not divide everything by three and use $1,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,15$?

"And in your example, why not divide everything by three and use 1,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,15
?" - @GerryMyerson the important of magic square it's the value we obtain... with my numbers I obtain 72 as a result from the sum of rows, columns and diagonals. After that division you mentioned the 72 value will change to 24.

And what makes $72$ more important than $24$?

And what makes 72 more important than 24?  @GerryMyerson It´s the symbolism... Kubera Yantra.

If the entries are all in arithmetic progression then the Lo Shu pattern is all there is. However, we may build $3×3$ magic squares in which not all entries are in arithmetic progression, as with
$\begin{array}
&4&11&3\\5&6&7\\9&1&8
\end{array}$
in which the smallest entry is adjacent to the second and third largest ones in its row. The pattern you give has the smallest entry flanked by the second and fourth largest ones. The entries in a $3×3$ magic square most generally have the form $a+mb+nc$ where $a,b,c$ are constants and $m,n\in\{0,1,2\}$. In the above example $a=1,b=2,c=3$ whereas the Lo Shu would have $a=1,b=1,c=3$.

As far as I understand, a 3x3 magic square must contain 9 distinct numbers in a particular arrangement, such that the sum of each row, column, and diagonal is the same. Is that correct?

Yes. The formula I give is the general one for the list of nine numbers.

Ok. I understand that we can use a broken sequence as you showed, but the flying numbers pattern position can´t be changed or can we?

What I mean, is, do we have always flying the numbers this way:
D I B
C E G
H A F

I'm asking this because I have a different flying numbers pattern:
G F B
A E I
HD C

I'm not sure what English word you mean, but “flying” isn't it.

@RuiPinto The first column of that magic square is G A H (or 7 1 8 if you prefer numbers), which adds up to 16, and the last column adds up to 14.

@Toph your claim of unequal sums is true if the numbers are from 1 to 9. But there are other sets of numbers for which that sequence gives equal sums. This answer offers such an example.

@Toph I can´t understand the way this texts boxes work... when I type the letters sequence for a 3x3 magic square in different lines, after hit enter the letters sequence appears in one line...???

Oh. But then don't these two patterns mean the same thing? Take G=4 F=9 B=2 A=1 E=5 I=9 H=8 D=4 C=3, and you'll get the Lo Shu pattern from  G F B A E I H D C. Is that valid? The letters aren't in increasing order any more... is that what Rui Pinto was asking about?

My new 3x3 Pattern is: Top Row: GFB; Middle Row: AEI; Lower Row: HDC.

Is there a way to share an image with a publication?

There is no way to do that in a comment.

Comments getting long, move to chat?

Just adding to the discussion around general $3\times 3$ magic squares.
Let's look for all $3\times 3$ squares of numbers such that every row, column and long diagonal sums to the same value.
We can deduce a lot in the $3\times 3$ case. Starting with
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix}$$
it should be clear that adding the same value to every entry will result in another magic square. In particular, we could subtract $e$ from every entry and still have a magic square; so let's just write $A=a-e$, $B=B-e$ etc to get
$$\begin{pmatrix} A & B & C \\ D & 0 & F \\ G & H & I \end{pmatrix}$$
Let's call the magic total in this square $S$. Using the fact that the centre cell is zero we have
$$\begin{pmatrix} A & B & C \\ D & 0 & S-D \\ S-C & S-B & S-A \end{pmatrix}$$
Adding up the top and bottom rows gives $a+b+c+3S-a-b-c=2S$; so we must have $S=0$. Updating the grid...
$$\begin{pmatrix} A & B & C \\ D & 0 & -D \\ -C & -B & -A \end{pmatrix}$$
(in particular at this point we see that the magic total is always three times the value in the centre). Now we know that $S=0$, let's look at the rows and columns that do not contain the centre; this gives us $B$ and $D$:
$$\begin{pmatrix} A & -A-C & C \\ C-A & 0 & A-C \\ -C & A+C & -A \end{pmatrix}$$
We've used every sum now; so the most general $3\times 3$ magic square (per this definition) just depends on three values ($A$, $C$ and $e$; although you could make other choices for the exact cells you specify).

Thank you @Chris Lewis. I don't want to understand or to learn how to do a 3x3 magic square. I know all that. My central question concerns to a new pattern that I use to make a 3x3 magic square. See the top publication that I've edited and updated.

The point is if you can find out everything you want to from this. You can prove that there is only one magic square using $1$ to $9$ from this. And if you want to explore further similar questions, this gives you a way to do it.
